# Boot issue with Windows Server 2003 R2 VM that was exported from Hyper-V on Server 2008 R2 and imported into Windows Server 2012

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

I am migrating some Hyper-V based Virtual Machiness from their current server which is running Windows Server 2008 R2 over to another box that is running Windows Server 2012.

I exported all of the VMs from the 2008 R2 system into folders on a network share and imported them into the new 2012 server.

All of the VMs running Server 2008 R2 as their guest OS fired up fine.

The one VM that was running Windows Server 2003 R2 x86 as its guest OS says it started okay via the Hyper-V manager, but the system never boots. It just hangs at a black window with a flashing cursor.

I re-exported the VM from the 2012 server and imported it into a 2012 R2 Hyper-V server and get the same results when trying to boot it.

Both servers are Dell PowerEdge servers and both have Intel processors in them, so it's not an AMD vs Intel issue.

Anything special that I need to do to get the 2003 R2 based VM to boot under 2012/2012 R2?

Comment: Aside from booting and looking at a black screen, have you attempted any diagnostics regarding the black screen at boot?  Like, have you attempted to start 2003 in Safe Mode? how long did you let it sit at the black screen before you gave up and powered it down?

Comment: I let it sit for about 20 minutes and nothing changed. Did the migration yesterday and gave up on the 2003 R2 VM when the SuperBowl started. Just re-started the 2008 R2 Hyper-V instance. Trying to figure out what (if anything) is special about 2003 R2 on 2012 Hyper-V.

Comment: The plan is to upgrade the VM to 2008 once I get it running on the new Hyper-V server since 2003 server is about to be EOL.